# Question about using a wired power strip to the electrical panel in home

Tags: electrical, grounding, wiring, ups

Because I have no wall outlet grounded anywhere in the house, I asked an electrician to help and the solution that didn't involved destroying the walls was to wire a power strip directly into the electrical panel (i got one right where the entrance is, I don't know the exact name but every wiring in the house comes from it )

Now the question I have for you specialists, is that power strip any different to a wall outlet if the wiring was done properly (meaning the cable of the power strip was cut, all three wires were connected in a free slot in the electrical panel)?

Power strip cable is 7 meters long, 6 sockets, 3500 W, 16 A, 50 Hz, 3x1.5 mmp and from what I see it has no other specifications like surge protection etc

So is one socket just like one wall-outlet? I want to connect just one UPS in this power strip (only grounded location i have) and go from the ups with the rest of connectors for PC and monitor. I won't be connecting anything else in this power strip.

Does this sound safe and reasonable to you or am I missing something (I have no clue about this domain)

Comment: This should be moved to the DIY (Home Improvement) site. What country are you in? In the USA, a licensed electrician would never do it this way. They would probably use conduit and surface mount boxes with normal outlets inside.

Comment: @Mattman944 We used power strip because it was the fastest way and had to go a few meters from the panel to the room. What is the functional difference between the powers trip wire and the regular wire + outlet? If I'd call him again to change things, wouldnt we just buy a cable + a surface mount box as you say(i assume it contains 1/2outlets? I have no idea what it looks like) and instead of the current power strip with 6 outlets we would have at the end a socket box? Is there any difference between those two?

Comment: Power strip cable usually has to be surrounded by a free-flow of air. If the one you bought does not tell you this then possibly it's OK but, the chances are is that it's not. This is a site that deals in design issues and this sort of fix question isn't really on-topic - you should ask stack exchange DIY for sure. If you want it leave to here, you need to provide links to the product and links to its data sheet/ blurb in order to verify it might be safe.

Comment: Single Outlet box. https://www.amazon.com/58361-1-Utility-Outlet-Construction-Galvanized/dp/B000HEKQRQ You can also buy double or triple wide. Wider boxes are normally for switches, so finding a cover plate may not be easy. Here is a triple, but I have never seen one in person. https://www.amazon.com/Enerlites-Receptacle-Standard-Stainless-7723/dp/B01M4RHRXS

Comment: @Andyaka This is the web page, sorry its not translated but google translate simply wont do the work https://www.dedeman.ro/ro/prelungitor-hoff-line-6-prize-7-m-3500w-3-x-1-5-mmp-intrerupator/p/1042016. Thanks for the answer

Comment: While this might be "safe", if it doesn't meet your local electrical code and there's a fire or any other incident, this installation may be blamed and you may be held liable, even if it wasn't the (entire) cause. This could lead to an insurance claim denial, or even worse, a death and possible imprisonment for you.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody here is going to tell you it's safe without seeing it, and possibly also testing it, for themselves.

But, you're not missing anything.  The sockets in the power strip are just sockets and you can plug the usual things in to them.  And the usual rules about not overloading sockets still applies.

Comment: I want to connect a UPS that's why I am extra worried https://www.cyberpower.com/eu/en/product/sku/cp1300epfclcd. Heard there are some issues with UPS and using power strips

Comment: @alindefaugh the UPS is rated well below the power rating of the power strip.  So I wouldn't be worried.

Comment: The electrician will be jumping in to provide the specific why this would be against NEC code.  Modifying the power strip from a plug to a direct connection now makes this a permanent wiring,  1) The cable now must meet specific specifications for wiring cable, which the power strip would not.  2) if exposed, then cable needs to be enclosed in proper conduit.  Proper way would be to install an surface outlet next to the panel with proper cabling.  Then plug your  power strip into the outlet.

Comment: @Programmer66 If I do this then I will connect an UPS into a power strip that is connected to a outlet thus having now 2 'jumps'. Isn't the recommended action to directly connect the UPS intro an outlet? I just want to know if it's safe to use, there is no danger to the wire as it's on the upper side of the wall, going around and entering the room trough a driller hole. It's not a cable that is floating around the house and you can just run into it. I only care if the cable and the connection are safe from an electrical perspective. Is there a named standard for the cable that I need to check?

Comment: @Programmer66 I rather doubt that the installation meets NEC codes, BS7671, or any other known standard.  Most likely, it's the "if it hasn't killed anyone yet, it must be OK" standard.

Comment: @SimonB Why would this be dangerous? I'm asking this seriously, The guy told me the electrical panel had an additional free spot for a connection and nothing but the cable is exposed. From my view, this is as dangerous as using a power strip anywhere because it's exposed but other than that I can't imagine what issues could there be. Again I am clueless in this domain so of course you may be right. I'm just asking. How different would be to use a separate cable + outlet box in the room? Is the cable the issue or the outlets on the power strip being different than a standard wall outlet?

Comment: @alindefaugh I can't tell if it's safe or unsafe, as I haven't seen it.

Comment: Update - I see that you are in the UK, where the US NEC codes would not apply.  What size breaker did the electrician connect the cable to?  And is the cable appropriate sized for the breaker (fuse) in the main panel?